# How to design a fair Synchronous Arbiter?

Tags: hdl

The problem i am facing is this, i need a Hardware circuit which decides fair between for example bus requests which happen at the same time.

Example:
A and B are the two components which do memory requests:

if A does alone an Request he is immediately accepted.
if B does alone an Request he is immediately accepted, too.

The tricky part come when they do a request at the same time, so it should be that they win at the same ratio.

How to design such an algorithm?
Which books do teach about such stuff?
Exists there some standard algorithms which do what i need (doesn't need to be hardware specific, but it should be easy to convert them in hardware)

**Edit 1**

How do i need to change the algorithm if i have > 2 components?
Would a counter for each component enougth which i count up if i had serviced the component, so i can easily decide which to serve if there are races?

Answer (score 1):

Each time A and B request at the same time, process the request from A. Next time this happens process the request from B. This seems fair. It's not hard to store the previous occasion.

Alternatively, process the A request if the previous non-colliding request came from B and vice versa.

Always expect the unexpected and it might be worth keeping a tally of servicing A and B. Let's say you create an 8 bit number where 127d is the neutral point meaning A and B have both been serviced identially in the past. You could increment this when A gets serviced and decrement it when B gets serviced. In this way you could examine how things were working out - if the number was getting too low you'd bias the colliding requests in favour of A.

This assumes that A and B do request at the same rate of course but more elaborate logging could be done to check the relative rates of servicing are living up to design expectations.

Comment: In the end it comes down to the fact, that you need some _state variables_ / registers.

Comment: round robin fashion, not bad :)